# Tunnelblick TLS error: The server has no TLS ciphersuites in common with the client

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I'm trying to set up an openVPN server and connect to it with Tunnelblick. My OpenVPN version is 2.4.3. and I'm using EastRSA-3.0.1. My certificates are using elliptical curve secp521v1.

openvpn log

> Thu Jul  6 14:56:25 2017 999.222.18.250:37144 TLS error: The server
>   has no TLS ciphersuites in common with the client. Your --tls-cipher
>   setting might be too restrictive. Thu Jul  6 14:56:25 2017
>   999.222.18.250:37144 OpenSSL: error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher Thu Jul  6 14:56:25
>   2017 999.222.18.250:37144 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
>   Thu Jul  6 14:56:25 2017 999.222.18.250:37144 TLS Error: TLS object ->
>   incoming plaintext read error Thu Jul  6 14:56:25 2017
>   999.222.18.250:37144 TLS Error: TLS handshake f

Here is my server.conf

```
dev tun 
proto udp
port 1194 
user nobody
group nogroup
ca ca.crt 
cert server.crt # SWAP WITH YOUR CRT NAME
key server.key # SWAP WITH YOUR KEY NAME
dh none
server 192.168.8.0 255.255.255.0 

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt 

# ncp-disable
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512

tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-128-CBC-SHA

tls-version-min 1.2
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8" 
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
compress lz4-v2 
push "compress lz4-v2"
keepalive 10 120
persist-key 
persist-tun 
tls-server
tls-auth /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ta.key 0
key-direction 0
status /var/log/openvpn2-status.log
log /var/log/openvpn2.log 
verb 3
daemon
```

client.ovpn

```
client
proto udp
dev tun
remote vpn.mydomain.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-client
ping 15
ping-restart 120
route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
route-nopull
key-direction 1
daemon
user nobody
group nogroup
<ca>
[Security-related line(s) omitted]
</ca>
<cert>
[Security-related line(s) omitted]
</cert>
<key>
[Security-related line(s) omitted]
</key>
<tls-auth>
[Security-related line(s) omitted]
</tls-auth>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was that I was using the wrong tls-cipher for elliptical curve certificates. The correct tls-cipher is

```
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
```